# SqlDataRecord.SetString - null string error

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core

We are using SqlDataRecord (just one field shown for clarity) this way:

```
SqlMetaData[] metaData = new SqlMetaData[1];
metaData[0] = new SqlMetaData("ItemName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200);

SqlDataRecord lineItemRecord = new SqlDataRecord(metaData);
lineItemRecord.SetString(0, itemName);
```

The problem is that it seems like `itemName` string in `SetString` cannot be null. If null is passed, then it throws exception saying its not a valid value.

How to pass null to stored procedure user defined type for field in type that is defined as `nvarchar NULL`?

Comment: did you try DBNULL?

Comment: SetString doesn't accept DBNull. only (int, string).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

possibly like this:

```
if(itemName == null)
{
    lineItemRecord.SetDBNull(0);
}
else
{
    lineItemRecord.SetString(0, itemName);
}
```

Comment: hm...dont know why i havent received notification about this answer. will test soon and come back with feedback. thanks!